# How do I export different types of data obtained from Bibliometrix using R?

Tags: r, export-to-csv, bibliography

I am new to R. I am wondering how I can export different types of data under 'S' as a .csv file for each list in 'S'.

Thanks.

```
results <- biblioAnalysis(M,sep = ";")
S <- summary(object = results, k = 10, pause = FALSE)
```

[image]

[image]

```
 dput(head(M, n = 1))
structure(list(AU = "WANG Y;LI L;LI P", DE = "GENE;  GENOME-WIDE ASSOCIATION STUDY;  GESTATIONAL DIABETES MELLITUS;  SINGLE NUCLEOTIDE POLYMORPHISM;  TYPE 2 DIABETES MELLITUS", 
    ID = NA_character_, C1 = "DEPARTMENT OF ENDOCRINOLOGY, SHENGJING HOSPITAL OF CHINA MEDICAL UNIVERSITY, LIAONING PROVINCE, SHENYANG, CHINA", 
    CR = "MCINTYRE, H.D., CATALANO, P., ZHANG, C., DESOYE, G., MATHIESEN, E.R., DAMM, P., GESTATIONAL DIABETES MELLITUSJ (2019) NAT. REV. DIS. PRIMERS, 5 (1); YANG, Y., GUO, F., PENG, Y., CHEN, R., ZHOU, W., WANG, H., OUYANG, J., XU, Z., TRANSCRIPTOMIC PROFILING OF HUMAN PLACENTA IN GESTATIONAL DIABETES MELLITUS AT THE SINGLE-CELL LEVELJ (2021) FRONT. ENDOCRINOL., 12; AUVINEN, A.M., LUIRO, K., JOKELAINEN, J., TYPE 1 AND TYPE 2 DIABETES AFTER GESTATIONAL DIABETES: A 23 YEAR COHORT STUDYJ (2020) DIABETOLOGIA, 63 (10), PP. 2123-2128; DAMM, P., HOUSHMAND-OEREGAARD, A., KELSTRUP, L., LAUENBORG, J., MATHIESEN, E.R., CLAUSEN, T.D., GESTATIONAL DIABETES MELLITUS AND LONG-TERM CONSEQUENCES FOR MOTHER AND OFFSPRING: A VIEW FROM DENMARKJ (2016) DIABETOLOGIA, 59 (7), PP. 1396-1399; JOHNS, E.C., DENISON, F.C., NORMAN, J.E., REYNOLDS, R.M., GESTATIONAL DIABETES MELLITUS: MECHANISMS, TREATMENT, AND COMPLICATIONSJ (2018) TRENDS ENDOCRINOL. METAB., 29 (11), PP. 743-754; BAZ, B., RIVELINE, J.P., GAUTIER, J.F., ENDOCRINOLOGY OF PREGNANCY: GESTATIONAL DIABETES MELLITUS: DEFINITION, AETIOLOGICAL AND CLINICAL ASPECTSJ (2016) EUR. J. ENDOCRINOL., 174 (2), PP. R43-R51; BARROSO, I., MCCARTHY, M.I., THE GENETIC BASIS OF METABOLIC DISEASEJ (2019) CELL, 177 (1), PP. 146-161; KOLB, H., MARTIN, S., ENVIRONMENTAL/LIFESTYLE FACTORS IN THE PATHOGENESIS AND PREVENTION OF TYPE 2 DIABETESJ (2017) BMC MED., 15 (1), P. 131; MAHAJAN, A., TALIUN, D., THURNER, M., FINE-MAPPING TYPE 2 DIABETES LOCI TO SINGLE-VARIANT RESOLUTION USING HIGH-DENSITY IMPUTATION AND ISLET-SPECIFIC EPIGENOME MAPSJ (2018) NAT. GENET., 50 (11), PP. 1505-1513; SANNA, S., VAN ZUYDAM, N.R., MAHAJAN, A., CAUSAL RELATIONSHIPS AMONG THE GUT MICROBIOME, SHORT-CHAIN FATTY ACIDS AND METABOLIC DISEASESJ (2019) NAT. GENET., 51 (4), PP. 600-605; FRANCAITE-DAUGELIENE, M., LESAUSKAITE, V., TAMOSIUNAS, A., GENETIC VARIANTS OF TCF7L2 GENE AND ITS COHERENCE WITH METABOLIC PARAMETERS IN LITHUANIAN (KAUNAS DISTRICT) WOMEN POPULATION WITH PREVIOUSLY DIAGNOSED GESTATIONAL DIABETES MELLITUS COMPARED TO GENERAL POPULATIONJ (2021) DIABETES RES. CLIN. PRACT., 172; KASUGA, Y., MIYAKOSHI, K., TAJIMA, A., CLINICAL AND GENETIC CHARACTERISTICS OF ABNORMAL GLUCOSE TOLERANCE IN JAPANESE WOMEN IN THE FIRST YEAR AFTER GESTATIONAL DIABETES MELLITUSJ (2019) J DIABETES INVESTIG, 10 (3), PP. 817-826; PERVJAKOVA, N., MOEN, G.H., BORGES, M.C., MULTI-ANCESTRY GENOME-WIDE ASSOCIATION STUDY OF GESTATIONAL DIABETES MELLITUS HIGHLIGHTS GENETIC LINKS WITH TYPE 2 DIABETESJ (2022) HUM. MOL. GENET; DIAS, S., PHEIFFER, C., ABRAHAMS, Y., MOLECULAR BIOMARKERS FOR GESTATIONAL DIABETES MELLITUSJ (2018) INT. J. MOL. SCI., 19 (10); HUANG, Y., RESEARCH PROGRESS ON SINGLE NUCLEOTIDE POLYMORPHISM AND LINKAGE DISEQUILIBRIUM (2004) BASIC CLIN. MED; SCHIERDING, W., O'SULLIVAN, J.M., CONNECTING SNPS IN DIABETES: A SPATIAL ANALYSIS OF META-GWAS LOCIJ (2015) FRONT ENDOCRINOL (LAUSANNE), 6, P. 102; CHENG, M., HUANG, X., ZHANG, M., COMPUTATIONAL AND FUNCTIONAL ANALYSES OF T2D GWAS SNPS FOR TRANSCRIPTION FACTOR BINDINGJ (2020) BIOCHEM. BIOPHYS. RES. COMMUN., 523 (3), PP. 658-665; HUANG, Q., GENETIC STUDY OF COMPLEX DISEASES IN THE POST-GWAS ERAJ (2015) J GENET GENOMICS, 42 (3), PP. 87-98; UDLER, M.S., MCCARTHY, M.I., FLOREZ, J.C., GENETIC RISK SCORES FOR DIABETES DIAGNOSIS AND PRECISION MEDICINEJ (2019) ENDOCR. REV., 40 (6), PP. 1500-1520; XU, N., ZHANG, T.T., HAN, W.J., ASSOCIATION OF CDKAL1 RS10946398 GENE POLYMORPHISM WITH SUSCEPTIBILITY TO DIABETES MELLITUS TYPE 2: A META-ANALYSISJ (2021) J. DIABETES RES., 2021, P. 1254968; HAN, W.J., DENG, J.Y., JIN, H., ASSOCIATION OF KCNQ1RS2237892C⟶T GENE WITH TYPE 2 DIABETES MELLITUS: A META-ANALYSISJ (2021) J. DIABETES RES., 2021, P. 6606830; SARHANGI, N., SHARIFI, F., HASHEMIAN, L., PPARG (PRO12ALA) GENETIC VARIANT AND RISK OF T2DM: A SYSTEMATIC REVIEW AND META-ANALYSISJ (2020) SCI. REP., 10 (1), P. 12764; LIANG, Z., DONG, M., CHENG, Q., GESTATIONAL DIABETES MELLITUS SCREENING BASED ON THE GENE CHIP TECHNIQUEJ (2010) DIABETES RES. CLIN. PRACT., 89 (2), PP. 167-173; WANG, X., LI, W., MA, L., INVESTIGATION OF MIRNA-BINDING SITE VARIANTS AND RISK OF GESTATIONAL DIABETES MELLITUS IN CHINESE PREGNANT WOMENJ (2017) ACTA DIABETOL., 54 (3), PP. 309-316; LIAO, S., LIU, Y., TAN, Y., ASSOCIATION OF GENETIC VARIANTS OF MELATONIN RECEPTOR 1B WITH GESTATIONAL PLASMA GLUCOSE LEVEL AND RISK OF GLUCOSE INTOLERANCE IN PREGNANT CHINESE WOMENJ (2012) PLOS ONE, 7 (7), P. E40113; CEBALLOS-CHAVEZ, M., RIVERO, S., GARCIA-GUTIERREZ, P., CONTROL OF NEURONAL DIFFERENTIATION BY SUMOYLATION OF BRAF35, A SUBUNIT OF THE LSD1-COREST HISTONE DEMETHYLASE COMPLEXJ (2012) PROC. NATL. ACAD. SCI. USA, 109 (21), PP. 8085-8090; LORENZO, P.I., MARTIN-MONTALVO, A., COBO VUILLEUMIER, N., MOLECULAR MODELLING OF ISLET BETA-CELL ADAPTATION TO INFLAMMATION IN PREGNANCY AND GESTATIONAL DIABETES MELLITUSJ (2019) INT. J. MOL. SCI., 20 (24); MELLADO-GIL, J.M., FUENTE-MARTIN, E., LORENZO, P.I., THE TYPE 2 DIABETES-ASSOCIATED HMG20A GENE IS MANDATORY FOR ISLET BETA CELL FUNCTIONAL MATURITYJ (2018) CELL DEATH DIS., 9 (3), P. 279; SHABANA, S.S.U., HASNAIN, S., IDENTIFICATION OF GENETIC BASIS OF OBESITY AND MECHANISTIC LINK OF GENES AND LIPIDS IN PAKISTANI POPULATIONJ (2018) BIOSCI. REP., 38 (4); HUANG, T., WANG, L., BAI, M., INFLUENCE OF IGF2BP2, HMG20A, AND HNF1B GENETIC POLYMORPHISMS ON THE SUSCEPTIBILITY TO TYPE 2 DIABETES MELLITUS IN CHINESE HAN POPULATIONJ (2020) BIOSCI. REP., 40 (5); ARORA, G.P., AKERLUND, M., BRONS, C., PHENOTYPIC AND GENOTYPIC DIFFERENCES BETWEEN INDIAN AND SCANDINAVIAN WOMEN WITH GESTATIONAL DIABETES MELLITUSJ (2019) J. INTERN. MED., 286 (2), PP. 192-206; KANTHIMATHI, S., CHIDAMBARAM, M., BODHINI, D., ASSOCIATION OF RECENTLY IDENTIFIED TYPE 2 DIABETES GENE VARIANTS WITH GESTATIONAL DIABETES IN ASIAN INDIAN POPULATIONJ (2017) MOL. GENET. GENOMICS, 292 (3), PP. 585-591; WANG, H., LI, J., LENG, J., THE CDKAL1 RS7747752-BILE ACIDS INTERACTION INCREASED RISK OF GESTATIONAL DIABETES MELLITUS: A NESTED CASE-CONTROL STUDYJ (2022) FRONT. ENDOCRINOL. (LAUSANNE), 13; LASRAM, K., BEN HALIM, N., BENRAHMA, H., CONTRIBUTION OF CDKAL1 RS7756992 AND IGF2BP2 RS4402960 POLYMORPHISMS IN TYPE 2 DIABETES, DIABETIC COMPLICATIONS, OBESITY RISK AND HYPERTENSION IN THE TUNISIAN POPULATIONJ (2015) J. DIABETES, 7 (1), PP. 102-113; RYOO, H., WOO, J., KIM, Y., HETEROGENEITY OF GENETIC ASSOCIATIONS OF CDKAL1 AND HHEX WITH SUSCEPTIBILITY OF TYPE 2 DIABETES MELLITUS BY GENDERJ (2011) EUR. J. HUM. GENET., 19 (6), PP. 672-675; PENG, D., WANG, J., ZHANG, R., CDKAL1 RS7756992 IS ASSOCIATED WITH DIABETIC RETINOPATHY IN A CHINESE POPULATION WITH TYPE 2 DIABETESJ (2017) SCI. REP., 7 (1), P. 8812; ZHAO, J., LI, M., BRADFIELD, J.P., EXAMINATION OF TYPE 2 DIABETES LOCI IMPLICATES CDKAL1 AS A BIRTH WEIGHT GENEJ (2009) DIABETES, 58 (10), PP. 2414-2418; AMIN, U.S.M., PARVEZ, N., RAHMAN, T.A., CDKAL1 GENE RS7756992 A/G AND RS7754840 G/C POLYMORPHISMS ARE ASSOCIATED WITH GESTATIONAL DIABETES MELLITUS IN A SAMPLE OF BANGLADESHI POPULATION: IMPLICATION FOR FUTURE T2DM PROPHYLAXISJ (2022) DIABETOL. METAB. SYNDR., 14 (1), P. 18; KANTHIMATHI, S., CHIDAMBARAM, M., LIJU, S., IDENTIFICATION OF GENETIC VARIANTS OF GESTATIONAL DIABETES IN SOUTH INDIANSJ (2015) DIABETES TECHNOL. THER., 17 (7), PP. 462-467; JIANG, G., HU, C., TAM, C.H.T., GENETIC AND CLINICAL VARIABLES IDENTIFY PREDICTORS FOR CHRONIC KIDNEY DISEASE IN TYPE 2 DIABETESJ (2016) KIDNEY INT., 89 (2), PP. 411-420; SAINZ, J., RUDOLPH, A., HOFFMEISTER, M., EFFECT OF TYPE 2 DIABETES PREDISPOSING GENETIC VARIANTS ON COLORECTAL CANCER RISKJ (2012) J. CLIN. ENDOCRINOL. METAB., 97 (5), PP. E845-E851; ROSTA, K., AL-AISSA, Z., HADARITS, O., ASSOCIATION STUDY WITH 77 SNPS CONFIRMS THE ROBUST ROLE FOR THE RS10830963/G OF MTNR1B VARIANT AND IDENTIFIES TWO NOVEL ASSOCIATIONS IN GESTATIONAL DIABETES MELLITUS DEVELOPMENTJ (2017) PLOS ONE, 12 (1), P. E0169781; XIE, K., CHEN, T., ZHANG, Y., ASSOCIATION OF RS10830962 POLYMORPHISM WITH GESTATIONAL DIABETES MELLITUS RISK IN A CHINESE POPULATIONJ (2019) SCI. REP., 9 (1), P. 5357; WANG, H., YANG, W., LIU, J., SERUM CONCENTRATIONS OF SFAS AND CDKAL1 SINGLE-NUCLEOTIDE POLYMORPHISM RS7747752 ARE RELATED TO AN INCREASED RISK OF GESTATIONAL DIABETES MELLITUSJ (2021) AM. J. CLIN. NUTR., 114 (5), PP. 1698-1707; WANG, K., CHEN, Q., FENG, Y., SINGLE NUCLEOTIDE POLYMORPHISMS IN CDKAL1 GENE ARE ASSOCIATED WITH RISK OF GESTATIONAL DIABETES MELLITUS IN CHINESE POPULATIONJ (2019) J. DIABETES RES., 2019, P. 3618103; BAI, Y., TANG, L., LI, L., THE ROLES OF ADIPOQ RS266729 AND MTNR1B RS10830963 POLYMORPHISMS IN PATIENTS WITH GESTATIONAL DIABETES MELLITUS: A META-ANALYSISJ (2020) GENE, 730; DE LUIS, D.A., PRIMO, D., IZAOLA, O., ROLE OF THE VARIANT IN ADIPONECTIN GENE RS266729 ON WEIGHT LOSS AND CARDIOVASCULAR RISK FACTORS AFTER A HYPOCALORIC DIET WITH THE MEDITERRANEAN PATTERNJ (2019) NUTRITION, 60, PP. 1-5; DE LUIS, D.A., IZAOLA, O., PRIMO, D., RELATION OF A VARIANT IN ADIPONECTIN GENE (RS266729) WITH METABOLIC SYNDROME AND DIABETES MELLITUS TYPE 2 IN ADULT OBESE SUBJECTS (2020) EUR. REV. MED. PHARMACOL. SCI., 24 (20), PP. 10646-10652; CHENG, J., LI, Y., HE, Q., ESSENTIAL HYPERTENSION IN PATIENTS EXPOSED TO HIGH-ARSENIC EXPOSED AREAS IN WESTERN CHINA: GENETIC SUSCEPTIBILITY AND URINARY ARSENIC METABOLISM CHARACTERISTICSJ (2021) J. TRACE ELEM. MED BIOL., 67; ZHOU, M., NING, N., JIANG, Y., CORRELATION OF ADIPOQ GENE SINGLE NUCLEOTIDE POLYMORPHISMS WITH BONE STRENGTH INDEX IN MIDDLE-AGED AND THE ELDERLY OF GUANGXI MULAM ETHNIC GROUPJ (2021) INT. J. ENVIRON. RES. PUBLIC HEALTH, 18 (24); DIVELLA, R., DANIELE, A., MAZZOCCA, A., ADIPOQ RS266729 G/C GENE POLYMORPHISM AND PLASMATIC ADIPOCYTOKINES CONNECT METABOLIC SYNDROME TO COLORECTAL CANCERJ (2017) J. CANCER, 8 (6), PP. 1000-1008; LI, W., YU, Z., HOU, D., RELATIONSHIP BETWEEN ADIPONECTIN GENE POLYMORPHISMS AND LATE-ONSET ALZHEIMER'S DISEASEJ (2015) PLOS ONE, 10 (4), P. E0125186; WANG, Z.D.J., YUE, X., ZHONG, J., EFFECTS OF ADIPOQ POLYMORPHISMS ON INDIVIDUAL SUSCEPTIBILITY TO CORONARY ARTERY DISEASE: A META-ANALYSISJ (2019) ADIPOCYTE, 137-143; DIAS, S., ADAM, S., RHEEDER, P., NO ASSOCIATION BETWEEN ADIPOQ OR MTHFR POLYMORPHISMS AND GESTATIONAL DIABETES MELLITUS IN SOUTH AFRICAN WOMENJ (2021) DIABETES METAB. SYNDR. OBES., 14, PP. 791-800; PAWLIK, A., TELER, J., MACIEJEWSKA, A., ADIPONECTIN AND LEPTIN GENE POLYMORPHISMS IN WOMEN WITH GESTATIONAL DIABETES MELLITUSJ (2017) J. ASSIST. REPROD. GENET., 34 (4), PP. 511-516; HOU, H., GE, S., ZHAO, L., AN UPDATED SYSTEMATIC REVIEW AND META-ANALYSIS OF ASSOCIATION BETWEEN ADIPONECTIN GENE POLYMORPHISMS AND CORONARY ARTERY DISEASEJ (2017) OMICS, 21 (6), PP. 340-351; HAN, L.Y., WU, Q.H., JIAO, M.L., ASSOCIATIONS BETWEEN SINGLE-NUCLEOTIDE POLYMORPHISMS (+45T>G, +276G>T, -11377C>G, -11391G>A) OF ADIPONECTIN GENE AND TYPE 2 DIABETES MELLITUS: A SYSTEMATIC REVIEW AND META-ANALYSISJ (2011) DIABETOLOGIA, 54 (9), PP. 2303-2314; KANG, J., LIU, C.H., LEE, C.N., NOVEL INTERLEUKIN-10 GENE POLYMORPHISM IS LINKED TO GESTATIONAL DIABETES IN TAIWANESE POPULATIONJ (2019) FRONT. GENET., 10, P. 89; LI, X., LAI, L., SU, J., NOVEL ASSOCIATION BETWEEN A TRANSIENT RECEPTOR POTENTIAL CATION CHANNEL SUBFAMILY M MEMBER 5 EXPRESSION QUANTITATIVE TRAIT LOCUS RS35197079 AND DECREASED SUSCEPTIBILITY OF GESTATIONAL DIABETES MELLITUS IN A CHINESE POPULATIONJ (2021) J DIABETES INVESTIG, 12 (11), PP. 2062-2070; WANG, X., LI, W., MA, L., ASSOCIATION STUDY OF THE MIRNA-BINDING SITE POLYMORPHISMS OF CDKN2A/B GENES WITH GESTATIONAL DIABETES MELLITUS SUSCEPTIBILITYJ (2015) ACTA DIABETOL., 52 (5), PP. 951-95", 
    JI = "CLIN. CHIM. ACTA", AB = "THE ASSOCIATION BETWEEN GESTATIONAL DIABETES MELLITUS (GDM) AND SINGLE NUCLEOTIDE POLYMORPHISMS (SNPS) HAS ATTRACTED GLOBAL RESEARCH ATTENTION. EXPLORING SNPS CAN HELP US FURTHER UNDERSTAND THE PATHOGENESIS OF GDM, PREDICT THE RISK OF GDM, AND GUIDE THE MANAGEMENT OF GDM PATIENTS. IN THIS REVIEW, WE SUMMARIZED THE STUDIES ON THE ASSOCIATION BETWEEN SNPS AND GDM, FOCUSING ON NOVEL SNPS PUBLISHED IN THE LAST 10 YEARS. THE SNPS IDENTIFIED TO BE ASSOCIATED WITH GDM INCLUDED HMG20A (RS7178572), CDKAL1 (RS7756992, RS7754840, AND RS7747752), ADIPOQ (RS266729 AND RS17300539), MTHFR (RS1801133), IL10 (RS3021094), CDKN2B (RS1063192), AND TRPM5 (RS35197079). HOWEVER, THE ROLE OF SNPS IN THE PREDICTION, DIAGNOSIS, TREATMENT, AND PROGNOSIS OF GDM, AS A POLYGENIC DISEASE, NEEDS TO BE FURTHER EXPLORED IN MULTIPLE ETHNIC POPULATIONS. © 2022 ELSEVIER B.V.", 
    PA = NA_character_, AR = NA_character_, chemicals_cas = NA_character_, 
    coden = "CCATA", RP = "LI, P.; DEPARTMENT OF ENDOCRINOLOGY, LIAONING PROVINCE, CHINA; EMAIL: LIPINGSJ@163.COM", 
    DT = "REVIEW", DI = "10.1016/j.cca.2022.11.010", BN = NA_character_, 
    SN = "00098981", SO = "CLINICA CHIMICA ACTA", LA = "ENGLISH", 
    manufacturers = NA_character_, molecular_seqnumbers = NA_character_, 
    TC = 0, PN = NA_character_, PP = "60-64", PU = "ELSEVIER B.V.", 
    PM = "36375523", DB = "SCOPUS", sponsors = NA_character_, 
    TI = "NOVEL SINGLE NUCLEOTIDE POLYMORPHISMS IN GESTATIONAL DIABETES MELLITUS", 
    tradenames = NA_character_, url = "https://www.scopus.com/inward/record.uri?eid=2-s2.0-85142221343&doi=10.1016%2fj.cca.2022.11.010&partnerID=40&md5=1515fe2ea8a6e122bc74618b5c0f985b", 
    VL = "538", PY = 2023, AU_UN = "SHENGJING HOSPITAL OF CHINA MEDICAL UNIVERSITY", 
    AU1_UN = "NOTREPORTED;NOTREPORTED;NOTREPORTED", AU_UN_NR = NA, 
    SR_FULL = "WANG Y, 2023, CLIN CHIM ACTA", SR = "WANG Y, 2023, CLIN CHIM ACTA"), row.names = "WANG Y, 2023, CLIN CHIM ACTA", class = c("bibliometrixDB", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you provide `dput()` in text form, not an image? If it's large, you can use `dput(head(M, n = 20))` to only post a portion of it.

Comment: @jrcalabrese I have edited the post. I am still figuring out how to export as a .csv file.